# Setting up htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am launching a site and want to set up an htaccess file to 301 redirect old links from the old site to the new site. I want it to be as helpful as possible, so I want to redirect specific links from the old site to pages with similar content on the new site.

What I want to accomplish is that if someone goes to www.oldsite/oldlink.html, they will be redirected to www.newsite.com/newlink.html, but if they go to any other page, they will be redirected to www.newsite.com/.

I know I can do the first part (redirecting a single page to another single page) with code like this in my htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /oldlink.html
http://www.newsite.com/newlink.html/
```

My question revolves around wanting to create a "catch-all" redirect for any links that I didn't specifically call out here because I didn't know they existed, etc. I know I can do this:

```
Redirect 301 / 
http://www.newsite.com/
```

But will that overwrite the oldlink.html redirect I created above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule oldlink.html http://www.newsite.com/newlink.html [NC,R=301,L] 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

(NC = No Case/Case insensitive; L = Last Rule)

If the first RewriteRule matches, the second will not be used. You can add as many Rules as you want.
You are also able to redirect http://www.oldsite.com/somelink.html to http://newsite.com/somelink.html (changing only "oldsite" to "newsite", not the pagename) by using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www.newsite.com/$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I would have given.  But just to add to it, be sure that you are aware that the rules are interpreted/applied in the order that they appear in the file.  Put the catch-all at the very, very end and be sure to "L" anything that should be the *final* answer when it comes to rewriting, otherwise it can just keep going down the rules for more matches.